# Tips on Handling an issue with arrays Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I have two arrays to display in a graph. I'm using chart.js.
For Y, I used the array of volumes and for X, the dates.
The indexes of an array correspond to the values ​​of the same index in the other array, for example:

```
var daysToDisplay = [12-01-2021, 13-01-2021, 14-01-2021]
```

and `volume = [1,2,3]`

then volume "1" corresponds to the first date and so on.

However, sometimes the dates are repeated (which should not happen on my graph).
What I need is: make the same dates become one and add all the volumes of these days in the same index as the date.

I'll put an example to make it easier to view

```
daysToDisplay = [12-01-2021, 13-01-2021, 13-01-2021, 13-01-2021, 14-01-2021]

volumes = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Become:

```
daysToDisplay = [12-01-2021, 13-01-2021 ,14-01-2021]

volumes = [1,9,5]
```

Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: How does `1-13` == `13-01`?

Comment: My mistake Mr.Polywhirl, already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the days to an array of pairs with their associated (by index) volume. Once you have the pairs, you can reduce them into an object with key (date) and the accumulated value of the volumes for each grouping. Now you can convert the object to entries and transpose them into two lists (key and value).

```js
const
  transpose = arr => arr[0].map((_, col) => arr.map(row => row[col])),
  dates = ['12-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '14-01-2021'],
  volumes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [ days, vols ] = transpose(Object.entries(dates
    .map((date, index) => [date, volumes[index]])
    .reduce((acc, [date, vol]) => ({ ...acc, [date]: (acc[date] || 0) + vol }), {})));

console.log(JSON.stringify(days)); // ["12-01-2021","13-01-2021","14-01-2021"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(vols)); // [1,9,5]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Here is the long version

```js
const
  dates = ['12-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '13-01-2021', '14-01-2021'],
  volumes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const
  pairs = dates.map((date, index) => [date, volumes[index]]),
  grouped = pairs.reduce((acc, [date, vol]) => {
    const prev = acc[date] || 0;
    acc[date] = prev + vol;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const
  days = Object.keys(grouped),
  vols = Object.values(grouped);

console.log(JSON.stringify(days)); // ["12-01-2021","13-01-2021","14-01-2021"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(vols)); // [1,9,5]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks for the tip Mr.Polywhirl, I will try to implement it in my code.